# Boolean modifier difference doing nothing

Tags: modifiers, svg

I'm currently modeling a mask to 3d print, and I'm using an extruded SVG in order to cut out the eye holes, using the Boolean modifier on the difference.

[image: screenshot 1]

When I apply the modifier, Blender only adds a 2d version of the SVG to my mask, behind where the hole should be. It doesn't actually cut out a hole.

[image: screenshot 2]

So far I have made sure normals all face the same way, that there are no doubles, and made the object manifold. It's still doing the same thing. I'm also on Blender 2.8, if that helps.

Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mksmWUowgF7f5jxy-soDC1dQipDLiqhS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Access denied to that file. Please upload to [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/help).

Comment: First, if you still have the original *mask* object use it. In the provided file you have applied the *Boolean* modifier. It did a cut ("2d version") and the mesh is no longer manifold which introduces more problems. If you don't have the original *mask* object you can fix it with the *Auto Mirror* addon. I couldn't test it with Blender 2.8 but it should work when you add and apply a *Remesh* modifier with method *Sharp* to the SVG first. This creates a better topology and the *Boolean* modifier should work then (tested in 3.3).